# set password for websvn in ubuntu server?

Tags: svn, apache, ubuntu, websvn

i have installed websvn using apt-get install websvn in ubuntu server.

i can now access websvn through http://url/websvn.

however, i want to set a password to the access, so only authorized people could access it.

how could i do this?

Comment: May be more appropriate on serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation at [Subversion repository browsing with authorization](http://blog.platinumsolutions.com/node/76)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are running late by 2 years

Comment: Don't take it personally, I'm just letting you know so you can update the link for the benefit of other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put in a .htaccess file in the root of the websvn folder:

http://www.duchnik.com/tutorials/vc/setting-up-and-configuring-websvn

Answer (score 0):

[Add User admin for repository authentication.](https://gotechnies.com/install-subversion-websvn-ubuntu-16-04/)

```
$ sudo htpasswd -c /etc/global.htpasswd admin
```

Open the `dav_svn.conf` file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf
```

Add the below line.

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
</Location>
<Location /svn/RepoName>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName \"RepoName Subversion Repository\"
 AuthUserFile /etc/global.htpasswd
 Require user admin 
</Location>
```

Please set the above correct **SVNParentPath**.
Make sure  apache2-utils is installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y apache2-utils
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```